# nginx stub status logging even though access_log off

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, logging

I have something pulling data from stub_status and it is clogging my logs even though I have logs turned off in that location...

nginx.conf:

```
...
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
...
```

my enabled site:

```
upstream app_server_exmaple {
    server 127.0.0.1:8500 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #Listens for www. and redirects
    server_name www.exmaple.com;
    return 301 $scheme://exmaple.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    #Listens for request on port 80 (http) and redirects them to https on port 443
    server_name exmaple.com;
    return 301 https://exmaple.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name exmaple.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exmaple.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/exmaple.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/exmaple/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/exmaple/exmaple/static_dump; 
    }

    location /stub_status {
    stub_status;
    access_log off;
    # Set to machine IP because netdata request is coming from the machine IP
    allow my.ip.add.ress;
    deny all;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        # Trying to serve LE auto-renew bot from here
    allow all;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server_exmaple;
        #Uncomment the following line and comment the previous 4 and run nginx -s reload to enable maintenance
        #return 503;        
    }

   error_page 503 @maintenance;
   location @maintenance {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /503.html break;
   }

   error_page 403 @forbidden;
   location @forbidden {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /403.html break;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So What was happening was that it was logging two of the first three server blocks where it redirects to ssl and non www and not logging the main server block.

The solution was to add

```
access_log /dev/null;
```

to each of those blocks and it went away